# Approximating the Rank

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $$L(C,s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$$ be the Dirichlet series of the Hasse--Weil L-function of an elliptic curve $C$ over $ℚ$. The modularity theorem implies that $L(C,s)$ is the $L$-function of a holomorphic cusp form for a congruence subgroup and it is entire function and have a holomorphic continuation. Also there is a **rapidly-converging series $f(s)$ expression $L(C,s)$ for any complex number $s$** given in http://modular.math.washington.edu/books/bsd/ on page 9.

My question is: I am not understood the word **half** (maybe mean almost the cases are zero not the exact number of those cases) in **Section 1.4.1. Approximating the Rank** (...Note that half of the
$L(k)(E, 1)$ are automatically $0$ because of equation (1.3.3)).

Comment: Presumably (1.3.3) is a functional equation for $L(C,s)$, where there is a sign $(-1)^{something}$, where the something depends on the elliptic curve $C$ and is even and odd half the time each. When it's odd, plugging in $s=1$ to both sides of the functional equation yields $L(C,1)=-L(C,1)$, forcing $L(C,1)=0$.

Comment: @GregMartin: I am asking about the term half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, this isn't what I thought at first: I thought they'd be talking about half the elliptic curves $E$, but they're really talking about half the derivatives $L^{(k)}(E,1)$ as $k$ varies, for a fixed $E$.

(1.3.3) reads
$$
(-1)^k \Lambda^{(k)}(E,2-s) = \epsilon\Lambda^{(k)}(E,s).
$$
(I've corrected a typo on the right-hand side). Here $\epsilon\in\{1,-1\}$ is some constant. In particular, setting $s=1$ gives
$$
(-1)^k \Lambda^{(k)}(E,1) = \epsilon\Lambda^{(k)}(E,1).
$$
If $\epsilon=1$, then this equation forces $\Lambda^{(k)}(E,1)=0$ for all odd $k$. If $\epsilon=-1$, then it forces $\Lambda^{(k)}(E,1)=0$ for all even $k$.